# In python 3.9+, how to write a type alias for the builtin tuple type with ellipsis? (mypy bug?)

Tags: python, types, type-hinting, mypy, python-3.9

### Short version

`tuple[int, ...]` is a valid type in python 3.9+ but `mypy` rejects a type alias for that. E.g. consider:

```
Thing = tuple[int, ...]
```

This results in "`error: Unexpected '...'`" (though python itself will load the module just fine).

Is this a bug in `mypy`?

What should/can I do? I thought maybe I could just use `NewType` instead but that fails in the same way.

### Long version

Python 3.9 incorporates [PEP 585](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/), meaning we can use built-in types such as `list`, `set` and `tuple` as generics; as such the versions in `typing` are now deprecated (e.g. see [docs for typing.Tuple](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/typing.html#typing.Tuple)).

`mypy` 0.800 [introduced support for this](https://mypy-lang.blogspot.com/2021/01/mypy-0800-released.html), so now I can write the following and `mypy` will type-check it correctly:

```
def foo(a: tuple[int, str]):
    ...
```

Now, `tuple` (and `typing.Tuple`) of course have a special form for homogenously-typed tuples of unknown length: `tuple[int, ...]`; this works fine too:

```
def foo(a: tuple[int, ...]):
    ...
```

Handily, [we can create aliases for types](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/typing.html#type-aliases), so this works too:

```
from typing import Tuple

Thing = Tuple[int, ...]

def foo(a: Thing):
    ...
```

Unfortunately, the following (which puts together `tuple`, the `...` form, and a type alias) does **not** work:

```
Thing = tuple[int, ...]

def foo(a: Thing):
    ...
```

Rather, this is rejected by `mypy` (v0.812) with the message "`error: Unexpected '...'`"

Python itself will load and run such a module just fine, however.

I haven't (yet) been able to find anything indicating that this shouldn't be possible.  So:

- Am I missing something? Is such a type alias in fact forbidden?
- If not, is this a bug in `mypy`?
- <s>Are there any better ways for working around this than just using `NewType` instead of an alias?</s>

  I thought using `NewType` would work around this (with some extra work) but it seems to fail in exactly the same way. So right now there seems to be no way to write these types and keep `mypy` happy.

Comment: Am I mistaken in thinking you can just use `tuple[int]` which will be seen as the equivalent?

Comment: @MarcelWilson That's a singlet tuple, which is different than `tuple[int, ...]`, which is a tuple of ints of non-fixed size.

Comment: This strikes me as a bug in mypy.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes, I've just discovered it's mypy issue 9980: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/9980 — I thought I'd done my research before posting the question but then I dug a bit deeper and there it is...

Comment: Do you really need to restrict the argument to `tuple` specifically, rather than using `Sequence[int]`?

Comment: (There are also `Container[int]`, `Iterable[int]`, `Collection[int]`, etc, depending on what your function need to do, exactly, with the argument.)

Comment: @chepner Thanks for those ideas... They're good points — but I've chosen to use `tuple` for its immutability, which is a guarantee I won't get with those other types (and AFAIK there aren't any that ensure it, as Python ABCs can't specify "doesn't implement X", right?). I'm afraid this is my time writing Haskell showing up in my Python... :-) Maybe I should relax a bit; I'll think about it.

Comment: The abstract classes don't prevent you from using tuples; they just allow other (theoretical) immutable types as well. It's not a *tuple* you want, per se, but an immutable object that can be indexed.

Comment: (Though to be fair, the hierarchy doesn't strongly differentiate between mutable and immutable types. The mutable variants reject immutable types, but I don't think there's a way to specify a type that *must* be immutable.)

Answer (score 2):

Aha, looks like [it is indeed an open mypy bug](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/9980).

So now the only question (until that's fixed/released) is how to work around it? Probably I have to bite the `NewType` bullet. :-/

---

Edit: hilariously, `Thing = NewType('Thing', tuple[int, ...])` fails in exactly the same way.